# c macros that integrated nested ifs

Tags: c

I want to make one macro to check is a char Upper or Lower case. I know how to make it with two macros, but my question is: Is it possible to have nested if condition in macro definition in c? Something like this:

`#define CHECK_CASE(x) (x >= 'a' && x <= 'Z') ? (x >='A' && x <='Z') ? 1 : 0 : 2`

In the above case I always receive 2.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the macro. It's the expression after expanding that evaluates

Comment: You use `'Z'` in both conditions. Doesn't seem right. I'd abandon the macro in favor of a readable function and use `isupper` and `islower`.

Comment: A macro can expand to just about anything.  Whether it's a good idea is another question.  These days, except in exotic circumstances, function-like macros offer nothing but disadvantages, and are generally discouraged.  It's a better idea to use functions everywhere, marking them explicitly `inline` if you think that will be useful.

Comment: First, why use a macro when you have isupper(3), which is optimized and might be a macro anyway?  Second, I suggest using a name that defines a result.  CHECK_CASE says nothing about the result.  IS_UPPER tells the reader that the result is true if the input is upper case.  (But then, you still have isupper(3).)

Answer (score 0):

If you are use ASCII, then `Z` will have a lower value than `a`. So, for any value `x`, the condition `(x >= 'a' && x <= 'Z')` will be false.

In ASCII, the letters are not contiguous, so your technique for detecting an alphabetic letter is not correct.

C provides an API to check if a character is an alphabetic character or not, `isalpha`. But, the value returned by this API is checking for either `isupper` or `islower`. So, your macro could be written as:

```
#define CHECK_CASE(x) (isalpha(x) ? isupper(x) ? 1 : 0 : 2)
```

While `isupper` and `islower` could return any non-zero value to represent true, boolean negation (`!`) must result in either `0` or `1`. We can use this to avoid needing to nest conditional expressions.

So, an alternative macro that retains your intended logic could be:

```
#define CHECK_CASE(x) (isalpha(x) ? !!isupper(x) : 2)
```

Or, we could flip the sense of the second test to avoid double negation:

```
#define CHECK_CASE(x) (isalpha(x) ? !islower(x) : 2)
```

The weakness of macros that uses its argument more than once is that if the argument is an expression, the expression gets evaluated multiple times. If the expression has a side-effect, the result of the macro may surprise the caller.

You can avoid this issue with an inline function instead:

```
inline int check_case(int x) {
    return (isalpha(x) ? !islower(x) : 2);
}
```

Comment: `inline` is not needed at all. It is ignored by the compiler which will decide if it will inline it or not. If you want to force the compiler you inline you need to use specific compiler pragmas or attributes for example in GCC  `inline __attribute__((always_inline)) bool check_case(int x)`

Comment: @0___________ Yes, a lot of things in the language is advisory to the compiler, and mostly documentation for code readers.

Comment: @SteveSummit How careless of me! You have my gratitude, I have addressed the error.

Comment: Thanks for explanation to all of you! It clear what I was trying to figure out!